# HTML5 Audio Safari Issue

Tags: html, safari, html5-audio

I am attempting to write my own HTML5 audio player: you can peek at it [here](http://www.guygar.com/inception/ultra/indexCopy.html).

It works fine in IE9, FF, Chrome but in Safari for some reason even though i have listened for

```
audio.addEventListener("loadedmetadata", tryThis, false);
```

It displays NaN *duration* data just before playing.

```
audio.setAttribute("src", a[trackNo][1]);
audio.load();
audio.addEventListener("loadedmetadata", tryThis, false);
```

---

```
function tryThis()
{
    this.addEventListener("timeupdate", function() { document.getElementById(radioPointer.toString()).innerHTML = formatTime(this.duration, this.currentTime);}, false);

    this.addEventListener("ended", function () { document.getElementById(radioPointer.toString()).innerHTML = formatTime(this.duration, 0); document.rootsPlaylist.roots[radioPointer].checked = false; }, false);

    this.play();    
}
```

---

```
<audio id="rootsPlayer" style="display:none;"></audio>
```

Could you offer any help please?

Many thanks.

NOTE: You have to flip between songs frequently to see what I mean, sorry I forgot to mention this.

Comment: Quick fix for this that I've used is to check isNaN():
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN
then set duration to 00:00 or another default value if its true

Comment: Yes, I have tried that already but that is not the style I am going for. Thank you for sharing.

Comment: Thanks for the input again, thought about it and in order to keep it simple I have adopted isNan()!

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is that `duration` property is initialized only after the `durationchange` event is emitted. So, you can either use `isNan()` function or some dummy `durationInitialized` variable:

```
var durationInitialized = 0;
audio.setAttribute("src", a[trackNo][1]);
audio.load();
audio.addEventListener("loadedmetadata", tryThis, false);
audio.addEventListener("durationchange", function() {durationInitialized = 1;}, false);
function tryThis() {
 this.addEventListener("timeupdate", function() {
  var time = '';
  if (durationInitialized) time = formatTime(this.duration, this.currentTime);
  else time = formatTime(this.currentTime);
  document.getElementById(radioPointer.toString()).innerHTML = time;
 }, false);

 this.addEventListener("ended", function () {
  var time = '';
  if (durationInitialized) time = formatTime(this.duration, 0);
  else time = formatTime(0);
  document.getElementById(radioPointer.toString()).innerHTML = time;  
  document.rootsPlaylist.roots[radioPointer].checked = false; 
 }, false);

 this.play();    
}
```